# Selecting millions of rows with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have many production servers (30+) which run the same application. It is required to do some processing on the combined values of a certain table in all these databases.

So, I created a table with required columns, and I will do the following:

1. connect to destination_server:database_name
2. connect to server_1:database_name, SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM the_table  //select ALL the table
3. Process each row and insert it in the destination server

Notes:

- Processing is almost trivial and I have LOTS of CPU/RAM on the machine which runs this node script.
- Each table contains 10million+ rows
- I plan to use [Streaming query rows](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows).
- Step 2 (connecting to source server) will be done in parallel for all the servers

Questions:

Will selection ALL the big table hit the performance on the production servers?

Is node suitable for such task?

Comment: selection of ALL rows might make the script hang for a very long time, i'll advise you to make the selection with limits, or use async module and especially `.cargo` or `.queue` to handle this.

Comment: @Phoenix will it block the script even when I use query streaming?

Comment: query streaming seems like generators in es6 can't really express an opinion since i haven't used them but the concept is almost the same - asyncronous as long as you approach the subject this way you won't have any issues

Comment: this seems ok, if you used specialised process/cluster for that. If you will trigger that in a process serving requests, performance will suffer a lot.